# Using params in a Delegate as a base class

Tags: c#, delegates, parameters, inheritance

I have a delegate expecting parameters of type A as parameters. So A is the base class. Class B and C inherit from A.

The problem is that although B and C inherit from the base class A, the DoSomething functions at the bottom of the script can't be converted to the delegate.

```
public class A { }
public class B : A { }
public class C : A { }

public delegate void CallbackAction(params A[] paremeters);
public class Main
{
    public int main(params string[] args)
    {
        CallbackAction callbackAction;
        callbackAction = DoSomething1;
        callbackAction = DoSomething2;
        callbackAction = DoSomething3;

        return 0;
    }

    public void DoSomething1(A arg0) { }
    public void DoSomething2(B arg0) { }
    public void DoSomething3(C arg0) { }
}
```

Is there any way to use params in a delegate and be able to use classes that have the params class as their base class?

When compiling the error I get is:
Error   5   No overload for 'DoSomething3' matches delegate 'SKConsole.CallbackAction'

I'm using .NET 4 and XNA

**EDIT::**
Ok let me explain why I am using this I am creating a console. This means a programmer using my console can add a command (console.AddCommand("help", Help) to the console, Help here is a function. When you are ingame and typing help in the console it will execute the function Help(). 
I now want it to work with console.AddCommand("setSpeed", SetPlayerSpeed) aswell. The SetPlayerSpeed function has 1 parameter, an int. But I want it to work with any function so if a programmer creates the function DoSomeFancyStuff(float a, string b, int c) I want the console to create a command and if you type in the correct string in the console execute these command.

I already tried making lots of delegates for different functions, but this is kinda ugly in my opinion.

What I then tried was the following

```
public abstract class SKConsoleParameter
{
    protected string value;

    public SKConsoleParameter(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public string GetRawValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public abstract bool IsValid();
    public abstract object GetValue();
}

public class StringParam : SKConsoleParameter
{
    public StringParam(string value) : base(value) { }

    public override bool IsValid()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class IntParam : SKConsoleParameter
{
    public IntParam(string value) : base(value) { }

    public override bool IsValid()
    {
        int i;
        return int.TryParse(value, out i);
    }

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(value, out i))
            return i;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Was this does is that if a developer creates a function like:

```
DoSomethingCool(StringParam s, IntParam i)
```

Then it can receive the values by using (string)s.GetValue() and (int)i.GetValue()
The StringParam and IntParam classes both inherit from SKConsoleParameter, so i though I could now create the follwoing delegate

```
void CoolDelegate(params SKConsoleParameter[] parameters)
```

But this doesn't work.. Because of the abstract problem with class A, B and C at the top of this page

Does anyone have any ideas to counter this problem?

Comment: What error are you recieving?  Can you use .NET 3.5 or .NET 4?  Have you considered using Action<T> instead of Delegate?

Comment: The error I receive is

Error 5: No overload for 'DoSomething3' matches delegate 'SKConsole.CallbackAction'

Comment: I'm posting some code that works using Action<T>...

Comment: Action<B> callbackAction;
    callbackAction = DoSomething1;
    callbackAction = DoSomething2;
    callbackAction = DoSomething3;

Seems to work, but It will only work for DoSomething1 and 2. So it works from B to A but not from A to B (and C). Cant it work the other way round?

Comment: OK supposing the cast worked, what should this do: `((CoolDelegate)DoSomethingCool)(new IntParam ("1"), new StringParam ("foo"))`?

Comment: @AntonTykhyy What it should do is dependend on what the DoSomethinkCool function does with it, maybe the user of my console whats to set the armor value of an entetie in the game, so it checks for the string foo on a gameobject and if it finds one it sets the armer to 1.

skConsole.AddCommand("setArmor", SetArmor);
void SetArmor(StringParam entitie, IntParam armorValue)
{

Comment: You missed the point of  my question -- the order of the two arguments is wrong so their types don't match the signature of DoSomethingCool.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy You are right... This is not going to work. I think if I actually want this to work I should start using Reflection.. Thanks for the help!! And I'll let you know when I made it work using reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your updated code -- try this.  As long as your method matches the delegate the contravariance should work as expected in .NET 3.5 or better

```
public abstract class SKConsoleParameter
{
    protected string value;

    public SKConsoleParameter(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public string GetRawValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public abstract bool IsValid();
    public abstract object GetValue();
}

public class StringParam : SKConsoleParameter
{
    public StringParam(string value) : base(value) { }

    public override bool IsValid()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public class IntParam : SKConsoleParameter
{
    public IntParam(string value) : base(value) { }
    public override bool IsValid()
    {
        int i;
        return int.TryParse(value, out i);
    }
    public override object GetValue()
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(value, out i))
            return i;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}   

class Program
{

    public delegate void CoolDelegate(params SKConsoleParameter[] parameters);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new StringParam("Glenn");
        var i = new IntParam("12");
        var coolDel = new CoolDelegate(DoSomethingCool);
        coolDel(s, i);
    }

    public static void DoSomethingCool(params SKConsoleParameter[] parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("parameters");
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            if (item is IntParam)
            {
                // do something interesting
                continue;
            }

            if (item is StringParam)
            {
                // do something else interesting
                continue;
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException("unknown param type");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed a solutions and I am probably gonna implemented it this way, however I am willing to also try and check if with reflection (probably uglier) I can make it work a little smoother for the user. If it works I'll leave both ways in the program, so the user himself can choose what to use. Thanks aggain!

Comment: Reflection has a significant impact on performance. I would avoid it in my core procedures and application logic.

Comment: this is only in the userfacing code so it should be a big problem

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the error in the wrong place. C# [allows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174.aspx) contravariance in delegates' input parameters. The problem with your code is that your delegate takes `params A[]`, while your method takes a single `A`. This is not allowed. Delcare your delegate as accepting a single `A`:

```
delegate void Callback1 (B a) ;
void Test11 (A a) {}
void Test12 (B b) {}

Callback1 c11 = Test11 ; // OK
Callback1 c12 = Test12 ; // OK
```

Note also that this does *not* work with array parameters:

```
delegate void Callback2 (B[] a) ;
void Test21 (A[] a) {}
void Test22 (B[] b) {}

Callback2 c21 = Test21 ; // compile error
Callback2 c22 = Test22 ; // OK
```

Comment: Is there to use the params in a delegate without using an array? Because I don't know the argument count of a function. What I want the best is a delagate that accepts any function, is this possible?

Comment: If you don't know the number of arguments, how are you going to call it? What's your use case? Possibly you have solved the easy half of the problem and what remains is the impossible half.

Comment: I don't think this `Callback1 c12 = Test12` compiles. Input parameters are contravariant, but your example needs covariance.

Comment: Ok let me explain something more, I am creating a console. This means a programmer using my console can add a command (console.AddCommand("help", Help) to the console, Help here is a function. When you are ingame and typing help in the console it will execute the function Help().

I now want it to work with console.AddCommand("setSpeed", SetPlayerSpeed) too. The SetPlayerSpeed function has 1 parameter, an int

Comment: @Henrik My bad, fixed. @Simon OK, where does this parameter come from? From the console line, I presume? How are you going to know how to parse it, i.e. which type the parameter is? How do you check the number of parameters? What happens if the number of parameters is wrong or the strings don't parse? You need to think this through. There are various implementations options available, none of them very pretty. The simplest and crudest one is probably [`MethodInfo.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k9x6bc0.aspx).

Comment: @SimonKarman also your question does not match your explanation of the use case, unless you consider `A` as `object` and `B` as `int`.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy in the use case the A is an SKConsoleParameter and B is an IntParam and C is an StringParam

Comment: Why create such interstitial classes instead of using plain `int`, `string` etc.? Either way you need to consider the questions in my longer comment above.

Comment: I just tried it, so a user of this console could also add it's own classes like IntBetween0and100Param, So this class contains code that makes sure the value entered by the user is between 0 and 100

Comment: I see, that's sensible. Since this is user-facing code, speed is not a concern. You should use Reflection to analyze the method signature (MethodBase.GetParameters ()), create the necessary arguments from strings (Activator.CreateInstance) and invoke the method (MethodBase.Invoke). Your AddCommand would receive a MathodInfo instead of the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 public class A {  }
public class B : A { }
public class C : A { }

public static class Helper
{
    public static Action<A> DoSomething;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        var b = new B();
        var c = new C();

        Helper.DoSomething = new Action<A>(DoSomething1);
        Helper.DoSomething = (Action<A>)new Action<B>(DoSomething2);
        Helper.DoSomething = (Action<A>)new Action<C>(DoSomething3);                       
    }

    public static void DoSomething1(A a) { }
    public static void DoSomething2(B a) { }
    public static void DoSomething3(C a) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think this will work if the number of parameters is variable

Comment: sure I see where you are going with this.